# Oracle : SQL Request with a Group By and a Percentage on two differents tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, percentage

I'm currently blocked on an complex request... (with a join) :

I have this table "DATA":

```
order | product
----------------
  1   |  A 
  1   |  B  
  2   |  A  
  2   |  D   
  3   |  A  
  3   |  C
  4   |  A  
  4   |  B
  5   |  Y  
  5   |  Z
  6   |  W  
  6   |  A
```

And this table "DICO":

```
    order | couple | first | second
    -------------------------------
      1   |  A-B   |   A   |   B
      2   |  A-D   |   A   |   D
      3   |  A-C   |   A   |   C
      4   |  A-B   |   A   |   B
      5   |  Y-Z   |   Y   |   Z
      6   |  W-A   |   W   |   A
```

I would like to obtain, on one line :

```
order | count | total1stElem | %1stElem | total2ndElem | %1ndElem
------------------------------------------------------------------
A-B   |  2    |       5      |    40%   |     2        |    100%       
A-D   |  1    |       5      |    20%   |     1        |    100%      
A-C   |  1    |       5      |    20%   |     1        |    100%         
Y-Z   |  1    |       1      |    100%  |     1        |    100%     
W-A   |  1    |       1      |    100%  |     5        |    20%
```

I'm totally blocked on the jointure part of my request. Somebody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any joins - just using `UNPIVOT` and `PIVOT`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE DICO ( "order", couple, first, second ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A-B', 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A-D', 'A', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A-C', 'A', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A-B', 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Y-Z', 'Y', 'Z' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'W-A', 'W', 'A' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT "order",
       "count",
       "1stElem_TOTAL" AS Total1stElem,
       100*"count"/"1stElem_TOTAL" AS "%1stElem",
       "2ndElem_TOTAL" AS Total2ndElem,
       100*"count"/"2ndElem_TOTAL" AS "%2ndElem"
FROM   (
    SELECT couple AS "order",
           key,
           COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY COUPLE )/2 AS "count",
           COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY VALUE ) AS num_value
    FROM   DICO
    UNPIVOT ( Value FOR Key IN ( first AS 1, second AS 2 ) )
)
PIVOT ( MAX( NUM_VALUE ) AS Total FOR key IN ( 1 AS "1stElem", 2 AS "2ndElem" ) );
```

**Results**:

```
order count TOTAL1STELEM %1stElem TOTAL2NDELEM %2ndElem
----- ----- ------------ -------- ------------ --------
A-D       1            5       20            1      100
A-B       2            5       40            2      100
A-C       1            5       20            1      100
Y-Z       1            1      100            1      100
W-A       1            1      100            5       20
```

Comment: It seems good, but I'm working on postgresql and impossible to work with PIVOT and UNPIVOT... !

And I'm not totally agreed with the solution, because if you just use the result in table dico : you will not catch the product A in the order n°7 : 7 | A (with no couple) : just one line in the order.

That why I want to work with the table DATA, to catch every occurence of A (couple or not couple)

Comment: @QuentinT. "I'm working on postgresql" Then why have you tagged the question Oracle? Also, if you have edge cases like that then you need to include them in the question so that people are aware of them; how can we be expected to know about it if you don't share all your requirements.

Comment: My bad, sincerely sorry : working on multiple database this time and I make this mistake ! Thanks for your help ! I will tag this question as Oracle and I will create a new one for postgreSQL.

Comment: You are totally right, sorry for my mistake. And thanks for this nice oracle solution.